# Do I need to worry about a leaning, 60 year old retaining wall?

Tags: retaining-wall

I have a 5 foot high retaining wall, made with CMU blocks, built in 1962. I don't have much information about (e.g. the shape of the footing, depth, etc) other than that it seems to be just a gravity wall, and doesn't even seem to have drainage behind it.

I've recently started measuring the plumb of the wall, and it seems to be out of plumb by about 4 inches in the worst spots (5 degree lean).

A surcharge (about 3 feet) of backfill (with its own retaining wall) seems to have been added onto on top of the original retained earth in 1972, about 2 feet back from the first wall.

Is fixing this wall/reinforcing it something I should be prioritizing within the next 15 years, or would you say it should be at the bottom of my priority list? If I were to try to fix it, what would the the most cost effective way to do so?

Comment: are there any cracks in it

Comment: Yea. Pretty big cracks. There's 3 cracks about 0.75 inch in diameter in different places in the wall.

Comment: If it failed, would there be damage done to structures or landscaping?  That is something you may wish to consider as you decide your priorities.

Comment: A 5 ft tall CMU wall near me collapsed after leaning more and more over time. It was along a sidewalk near an elementary school that kids would walk along and adults would push baby strollers. I used to walk my dog along it until I got concerned. The collapse happend at night during a heavy rain so no one reported on the timescale of the collapse. New owners of the property replaced it with a proper block wall that looks great and is staggered back.

Comment: Don't forget, @JimStewart, that when it was built, that 5' tall CMU wall was a "proper block wall". Understanding increases, technology changes and things improve. Just because it doesn't meet current standards doesn't mean it wasn't done well for the time.

Comment: A leaning CMU wall could drop blocks on a beloved pet or a child. I favor the use of the blocks that are 40 lb each and are locked together with fiberglass epoxy pegs or equivalent. I wonder if these truly require behind and through the wall underground drainage piping that some people put in since water can seep between the blocks.

Comment: One particular brand of these dry stack block engineered wall systems allows griping the blocks on their top surfaces with a special holder so no fingers in the way when setting the blocks.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson it's at the back of the property, so no major damage to structures. But it's at the property line so it could expose me to liability. The code restrictions severely restrict what I can do with the wall, given that it's so close to the property line...

Comment: If it has cracks, it is under stress, if it is under stress it will come down eventualy

Comment: So is the wall leaning over someone else's property? If so, there would be liability from that. Thirty years ago we had a dry stack block engineered wall built on our property line with the house downhill of us. It has not moved and is sound as can be.

Comment: No the wall is not leaning over someone elses property, but it is supporting the land on someone else's property... I might try the dry stack block wall, but the unfortunate part is that all walls need to be stamped by engineering if they are too close to the property line, which would add considerable expense and oversight.....

Comment: Is the leaning CMU wall entirely on your property?

Comment: Yea, it's leaning over my property. Nothing too important in the way. But it would make the neighborhors side slide down, though they don't have anything important there either.